# Adicionar e remover class JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou com um efeito toggle que abre e fecha uma div, e nesse efeito, coloquei pra adicionar uma class e remover. Ele adiciona a class, mas não está removendo a mesma. Por que?

### JQuery

```
$j('.filters__filter.tamanho').click(function(){
    $j('.filters__filter.tamanho .ul--0').slideToggle(150);
    //remove class active
    $j('.filters__filter.tamanho').removeClass('active');
    //adiciona class active ao item clicado
    $j('.filters__filter.tamanho').addClass('active');
});
```

---

Se eu clico de novo, a class active

Comment: Você esta mandando ele remover a classe e em seguida você adiciona ela novamente?

Comment: É, ficou confuso kk, ja tentei tanto fazer isso aqui, que não estou conseguindo. Como faço pra ele adicionar ao ser selecionado, e ao ser clicado de novo ou outra div for selecionada, ele remover a class? Existe alguma forma ou no próximo codigo de div selecionada, vou ter que mandar remover a dessa div? Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let filtersSize = jQuery('.filters__filter.tamanho')
filtersSize.on('click', function() {
    filtersSize.find('.ul--0').slideToggle(150)

    // toggle active class
    filtersSize.toggleClass('active')
})
```

Tenta isso aqui brother.. toggleClass vai alternar a classe..

Comment: Muito obrigado Drik, simples e resolveu meu problema, não lembrava do toggleClass. Mais uma vez, obrigado!

Comment: Fecho brother, é nois!

Comment: `$j('.filters__filter.tamanho').toggleClass('active');` vai fazer toggle a todos os elementos (!). Se todos tiverem sem class `active` qualquer um que seja clicado faz com que todos fiquem com a classe `active`...

Answer (score 2):

Se tens vários elementos e queres que remover a classe a todos os que não foram o clicado (e ter toggle da class no clicado) podes fazer assim:

```
var filtros = $j('.filters__filter.tamanho');
filtros.click(function(e){
    filtros.each(function(){
        if (this == e.currentTarget) $(this).toggleClass('active').slideToggle(150);
        else $(this).removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

Assim removes a classe em todos, e fazes toggle do que foi clicado.

Comment: Sergio, acho que só não tem a necessidade de fazer um `foreach` nos filtros, basta apenas remover todos os ativos `filtros.removeClass('active')` e como você está no escopo do click, o `this` é o elemento que foi clicado, então é só executar diretamente `$(this).toggleClass('active').slideToggle(150);` https://jsfiddle.net/L4Lfa7r3/

Comment: @PedroCamaraJunior quando fazemos `filtros.removeClass('active')` ele corre um `each` na mesma internamente para tirar a classe um a um. Daí que com a minha solução poupa-se uma execução extra quando o `this == e.currentTarget`. Mas concordo que ficaria 2 linhas mais compacto.

Comment: Concordo com seu ponto também, mas particularmente prefiro o código mais limpo. :)